# DC circuit theory: Equivalent resistance help

Tags: resistors, dc

In the given DC circuit, I need to calculate resistance \$R_{2}\$:

if the equivalent resistance between nodes *1* and *2* is \$R_{e}=100 ohm\$

I get the value \$R_{2}=36.36ohm\$

\$R_{1}\$ and \$R_{3}\$ are parallel, \$R_{2}\$ and \$R_{4}\$ are parallel.

Sum of \$R_{1,3}\$ and \$R_{2,4}\$ gives \$R{e}\$.

Is this right?

[image]

Comment: Looks good flight.

Comment: It is good to go....

Comment: If you can calculate 36.36 ohms then you can surely reverse that back to 100 ohms and prove it to yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You're right.

Two things to know :

Series : Rs = R1 + R2

Parallel : Rp = R1*R2 / (R1 + R2) or 1/Rp = 1/R1 + 1/R2

Here, you've got

```
R1 = 100;
R3 = 200;
R4 = 400;

Re = 100;

Ra = R1*R3/(R1 + R3) (considering Ra is the upper branch equivalent resistor)
Rb = Re - Ra (which is equal to R2//R4 = R2*R4/(R2 + R4))
```

You find Rb is 33.333 Ohm. Now you can compute :

```
1/Rb = 1/R2 + 1/R4 
1/33.333 = 1/R2 + 1/400
1/R2 = 1/33.333 - 1/400 = 0.0275
R2 = 1/0.0275 = 36.3636
```

Then you can check the answer by R1//R3 + R2//R4 = Re.

Answer (score 0):

There are two rules to know when trying to combine resistances together.
Series resistances add together, resistors in parallel are more complex.

The formula for calculating the effective resistance of 2 or more resistors in parallel is: 
[image]

Your question actually contains an error and it doesn't make sense.

You can combine R1, R3:

R13 = 1/ ((1/100) + (1/200))
      = 66.6 ohms.

The reduced circuit then comprises:
R13 in series with (R2 and R4 in parallel)

But you can't do any further analysis because you have then have resistor R2 in parallel with R4 but you don't say what the value of R2 is, so you can't calculate a combined resistance.  And this is where your question is incomplete.

Comment: But I have the equivalent resistance \$R{e}=100ohm\$

Answer (score 0):

@Dean has the right idea, but missed the fact that you know Re = 100 Ohm.

Carrying on, you know R13 + R24 = Re, so R24 = Re - R13 = 33.3 Ohm.

Now you need to use the formula Dean gave to solve for R2, given that R24 = 33.3 and R4 = 400. I'll leave that as an exercise :)

Comment: EBlake, yes, I did miss that fact in the original question! Thanks!